# Maintaining aspect ratio of Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the following html

```
<div class="ex1">
   <iframe class="ex2" src="video link"></iframe>
</div>
```

The div and iframe are both absolutely positioned.

I need the iframe to maintain an aspect ratio of 16:9 as the screen gets larger or smaller. How can I accomplish this?

I tried using

Here's my CSS:

```
.ex1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}

.ex2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    max-height: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Could you not simply adjust the width and height of ex2? Like `height: 100%; width: 56.25%;`